# sudo using PATH ahead of fully qualified executable

Tags: sudo

I ran into a problem that I've never seen before and can't exactly explain.  I was helping someone run a perl based install on a RedHad 4.6 zLinux and running under sudo seemed to grab the system perl rather than the fully qualified perl executable.

Example:

```
/my/perl/bin> ./perl -v == 5.8.8
/my/perl/bin> /my/perl/bin/perl -v == 5.8.8
/my/perl/bin> sudo /my/perl/bin/perl -v == 5.8.5????
```

Even though we were fully qualifying the path to our perl it was still grabbing /usr/bin/perl when running under sudo. I have no idea why, any gurus know?

Comment: please use code formatting. The command line snapshots are barely readable.

Comment: This question belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: Is there any chance /my/perl/bin/perl is a shell script?

Comment: Nope, not a shell script it's the exe

Answer (score 0):

preserve environment:

```
sudo -E /my/perl/bin/perl -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit you sudoers config :

```
sudo gedit /etc/sudoers
```

add this line

```
Defaults env_keep +=PATH
```

this is similar to `sudo -E`but persistent.

Answer (score 0):

check if your sudoers file has the the secure_path option set if so then that is your PATH

`Defaults   secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"`